# python re regex split after \\. os.linesep for whitespace between and not

Tags: python, regex

I want to split Test after the period whether or not the line ends in whitespace

```
Test="""
This works.
but this does not because of the whitespace after the period. 

This line not sepearated.
test. don't split here!  
or here
or here
"""
```

My attempt splits when there is no whitespace

```
cmds = re.split("(?<=\\.)%s[\t]*"   %    os.linesep, Test, flags=re.M)
```

I want to split in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

Test="""
This works.
but this does not because of the whitespace after the period. 

\t     This line not sepearated.
test. don't split here!  
or here
or here  \n    """

r = re.compile('(?<=\.)\s*?^\s*|\s*\Z|\A\s*',re.M)

print '\n'.join(map(repr,Test.splitlines(1)))
print
pprint( r.split(Test) )
```

result

```
'\n'
'This works.\n'
'but this does not because of the whitespace after the period. \n'
'\n'
'\t     This line not sepearated.\n'
"test. don't split here!  \n"
'or here\n'
'or here  \n'
'    '

['',
 'This works.',
 'but this does not because of the whitespace after the period.',
 'This line not sepearated.',
 "test. don't split here!  \nor here\nor here",
 '']
```

### EDIT

`\A` and `^` are zero-length matching symbols,
they match the **position situated at the very beginning of a string**

```
print [m.start() for m in re.finditer('\A','a\nb\n\nc\n')]
# prints [0]
print [m.start() for m in re.finditer('^', 'a\nb\n\nc\n')]
# prints [0] too
```

If the `re.MULTILINE` flag is specified in the definition of a regex, then the signification of `^` is extended to the positions situated just after the newline character `\n`.
These additional positions are matched by `(?<=\n)`

```
print [m.start() for m in re.finditer('(?<=\n)', 'a\nb\n\nc\n')]
# prints [2, 4, 5, 7]
```

So,  when `re.MULTILINE` flag is activated in a regex, `^` is equivalent to `\A|(?<=\n)`, it matches **the very beginning of a string and all the positions just after newlines**; on a display these positions are seen as all the heads of lines.  The vertical bar `|` means OR.

```
print [m.start() for m in re.finditer('^','a\nb\n\nc\n',re.M)]
print [m.start() for m in re.finditer('\A|(?<=\n)','a\nb\n\nc\n')]
# they print [0, 2, 4, 5, 7]
```

The signification of a zero-length matching symbol is put in evidence with `^` in this little code

```
print [m.span() for m in re.finditer('^','a\nb\n\nc\n',re.M)]
# prints [(0, 0), (2, 2), (4, 4), (5, 5), (7, 7)]
```

There are 7 characters in the string represented as `'a\nb\n\nc\n'`

---

```
re.compile('(?<=\.)\s*?^\s*|\s*\Z|\A\s*',re.M)
```

There are three partial patterns in the total pattern. It can be better seen writing like this:

```
re.compile('(?<=\.)\s*?^\s*'
           '|'
           '\s*\Z'
           '|'
           '\A\s*',
           re.M)
```

In my pattern, `(?<=\.)` expresses a mandatory position just after a dot `.`
and `^` expresses a mandatory presence of a position just after a newline `\n`.
The `\s*` between them expresses, as you said, optional whitespaces.
So `(?<=\.)\s*?^` expresses a succession of whitespaces beginning just after a dot and ending just after a newline.

`*` is a greedy quantifier : that means it gives instruction to the regex engine to consume as many quantified characters as possible. Then if the regex pattern was `(?<=\.)\s*^` , the position matching with the symbol `^` in the pattern would be the LAST possible one, as far after the dot as possible.
Putting `?` after a quantifier annihilates its greedy behaviour. So `(?<=\.)\s*?^`     means that `\s` must match as many whitespaces before bumping into the FIRST position just after a newline that will be encoutered.
If you prefer, it is equivalent to `'(?<=\.)[ \f\r\t\v]*\n`

After that match, the ending `\s*` means that the matching must go on until additional whitespaces are found after the beginning match between the two positions after a dot and after a newline. As `\n` is one of the whitespaces symbolized by `\s`, this ending `\s*` makes the engine motor to progress through all the following lines as long as there is no other characters as whitespaces to stop it.

So, every sentence ending on a dot inevitably followed somewhere in the subsequent characters by a newline will be split according to the succession of whitespaces containing at least a newline that follows the sentence.

.

But what for a last dot in the string, only followed by whitespaces all different from `\n` ?
In this case the succession of these non-newline whitespaces won't match and the last line wont be split from the trailing whitespaces.
In order to eliminate this trail, I put the pattern `\s*\Z` as an alternative pattern according which the split will be done. So the last line until the last non-whitespace character will be split from this trail.
This being an alternative , it is separated from the first partial pattern `(?<=\.)\s*?^\s*` with a vertical bar meaning OR.

The same can be done for a potential heading of whitespace: the alternative pattern `\A\s*` will match such a potential heading and the first line will correctly stripped off of these whitespace at beginning of the string.

.

**NOTA BENE**

In fact, the question mark isn't necessary in the pattern.

`(?<=\.)\s*?^\s*`
will match exactly the same portions of string as
`(?<=\.)\s*^\s*`
The only difference is that the `\s*?` matches all the whitespaces until the position just after the FIRST newline after the dot,
while the `\s*` of the second pattern matches all the whitespaces until the position just after the LAST newline possible.
This presents no problem: if there are several newlines after the dot, it means there is at least one after it, all these newlines being separated with non-newline whitespaces.

By the way, the following pattern works too:
    `(?<=\.)\s*\n\s*`

The following pattern is probably the more efficient pattern:
    `(?<=\.)[ \f\r\t\v]*\n\s*`

Comment: This works very well!  Xtra credit: can you quickly say why it works. and why the ?^\s* is important.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly the problem. I imagined that you want to split according dots only if they are at the end of a line, that is to say if there are only whitespaces between a dot and the line separator. So I used ``^`` with ``re.M`` in order that it means "beginning of a line". So ``\s*?^`` leads the regex motor until the beginning of the following line: we are sure that the dot is before an end of line. Then ``\s*`` consumes the possible following whitespaces.

Comment: But I'm not satisfied with my pattern, because ``^`` combined with ``re.M`` means the position just after a ``\n`` character. However there are OS that doesn't use ``\n`` for line break but only ``\r``. It would be better to know the origin of the text. For example if a text file is read in a non-binary mode, Python's universal newline support transforms all brakes of lines into ``\n``

Comment: I'm parsing SPSS syntax code in WindowsOS so i can error check each command (which are terminated with dots).  I can read it in any which way:with open(init_Syntax,'rb') as f:   Thanks for the explanation, i'm studying it!

Comment: In fact, my regex pattern is a little uncommon because I was troubled with the presence of ``os.linesep``, it gives the impression that the line separator can change, either from data to data, or from OS to another OS. That said, my regex pattern is stupid as it supposes that there is always ``\n`` that constituts the line separator. The point to know is : will the lines be separated with a pattern that will always contain ``\n`` or not ? Line separatour may be ``\r`` , ``\n`` , ``\r\n`` , and maybe some other exotic patterns. The most common is there is always ``\n``. Is it your case ?

Comment: OK, so if there is always ``\n`` in the line separator, my regex pattern fits to your need. But I improve it to take account of what may happen at the end of the text: use ``re.compile('(?<=\.)\s*?(?:^|\Z)\s*',re.M)`` . It is important to let ``\Z``, not ``$``. You can perform tests to undertsand what happens according how the text ends.

Comment: Just a question more. Do you want to split according to a dot that is right in the middel og a line, that is to say separated with letters from the end of a line ? Or not ?

Comment: Ahem.... my last suggestion is ``re.compile('(?<=\.)\s*?^\s*|\s*\Z|\A\s*',re.M)`` : it removes the whitespaces at the beginning and at the end of the text

Comment: There's a lot of misunderstanding in the manner you intepret the elements of a regex pattern. I must do an edit in my answer to explain things precisely. I hope there's no urgency for you to understand these points because I have not enough time for the moment. I will do this edit. If it would be too long to come, don't hesitate to remind me to do it.

Comment: after dot, search for optional whitespace (\s*?), check whether it's a new line (^\s*), now strip out white space from beginning \A\s*) and end of strings (\s*\Z).

Comment: As you deleted your comment in which there were some misconceptions, I didn't remind what were the points I wanted to explain. However I explained my regex pattern (really simple indeed in fact), probably in a too long way

Answer (score 0):

If it is okay to also strip the trailing whitespace from the lines that end in whitespace, you can use the following:

```
re.split(r'(?<=\.)[ \t]*%s' % os.linesep, Test, flags=re.M)
```